# Exclude object's field from pickling in python

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to avoid pickling of certain fields in an instance of a class.
Currently, before pickling I just set those fields to None, but I wonder whether there's more elegant solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is an example [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects) which solves your problem with `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`.

Comment: fixed the link again

Answer (score 58):

One way to handle instance attributes that are not picklable objects is to use the special methods available for modifying a class instance's state: `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()`. Here is an example

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, value, filename):
        self.value = value
        self.logfile = file(filename, 'w')

    def __getstate__(self):
        """Return state values to be pickled."""
        f = self.logfile
        return (self.value, f.name, f.tell())

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """Restore state from the unpickled state values."""
        self.value, name, position = state
        f = file(name, 'w')
        f.seek(position)
        self.logfile = f
```

When an instance of `Foo` is pickled, Python will pickle only the values returned to it when it calls the instance's `__getstate__()` method. Likewise, during unpickling, Python will supply the unpickled values as an argument to the instance's `__setstate__()` method. Inside the `__setstate__()` method we are able to recreate the file object based on the name and position information we pickled, and assign the file object to the instance's logfile attribute.

Reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pypers.html

Comment: The link at the end of this answer is broken.

Answer (score 27):

Pickling uses the object's `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods; you can override them and ignore the fields you want.

```py
# foo.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 1
        self.baz = 2

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        # Don't pickle baz
        del state["baz"]
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)
        # Add baz back since it doesn't exist in the pickle
        self.baz = 0
```

```py
# main.py
import pickle

from foo import Foo


foo = Foo()
print(f"Foo bar: {foo.bar} baz: {foo.baz}")

new_foo = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(foo))
print(f"New bar: {new_foo.bar} baz: {new_foo.baz}")
```

Output:

```
Foo bar: 1 baz: 2
New bar: 1 baz: 0
```

You can find another example here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects

Comment: The other answer used `state` as a `tuple`, whereas this one used it as a `dictionary`.  It seems that `state`'s type is determined by `__getstate__`'s return type

Comment: Take care, this also drops anything in `__slots__` and won't work if `baz` is `__baz`.

Comment: If `baz` is set in `__init__`, do only need to set it in `__setsate__` because you want a different default value there?

Answer (score 0):

For those whose classes define `__slots__`, and therefore do not have `__dict__` for use as suggested in the current answer, the following solution will work:

```py
class Foo:
    __slots__ = ('a', 'b', 'bad_attr')

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.bad_attr = 'foo'

    def __getstate__(self) -> dict:
        return {
            attr: getattr(self, attr) for attr in self.__slots__
            if attr not in ('bad_attr', ) # Attributes to exclude
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state: dict) -> None:
        for attr, value in state.items():
            setattr(self, attr, value)
```