# Python Multiprocessing - cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get data posts from twitter using twint, and to make it faster i'm using multiprocessing to get all data from all users in parallel.
For some reason, I always get the error:

```
cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

I can't find how to fix it.. I tried using 'threading' but for some reason it doesn't give me full data and every time give me different result.

Thank you!

for loop than creating processes like that:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_func, args=(current_user, collection, posts_list,))
proc.append(p1)
p1.start()
```

after that for loop the doing for each process 'join'.

Comment: I guess you have a lock in an object you are passing the process you create with `multiprocessing` and you can't do that. You can't pass anything to a process (because it uses `pickle` to serialize them). Maybe post the code you are using so it'll be clearer what you're doing

Comment: It's hard for me to post the code because it very clumsy. I'm sending a function three variables and the function's target it to return me all posts of each user and user - all will get into a list.

Comment: You probably have some `lock` somewhere inside `current_user`/`collection`/`posts_list`

Comment: What does it mean ? How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the lock you probably have inside one of the arguments, because `lock` is an object that can't be pickled. Multiprocessing uses (as the name suggests) multiple processes, and the argument passing to a process is made with `pickle`.

Therefore you can either remove the lock object, or ignore it while pickling. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345944/exclude-objects-field-from-pickling-in-python) post to do that

Comment: I found the the problematic is collection.. I'm using collection to update database and upload all posts from today.. what is the problem in that?

Comment: Yeah, when using as Database Manager (at least in my case, MongoDB and its python driver pymongo), it's better to pass the cursor directly to the function that is going to be parallelized, than pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited description you post, we cannot tell more about the error. That should relate to the `lock` thing as the others mentioned.

But I guess you're running your program on Windows. And maybe there is some error of twint running on Windows with multiprocessing. Windows system cannot do fork which Unix system uses to create a new process. If you also see error info like `spawn xxx`, then, I think, it could probably be an error of multiprocessing program running on Windows. But I currently don't have solution for this. Wait for others to provide solutions.