# How to disable pickling?

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I have a class where some user may try to pickle it.

If they do, what I would like to do is:

1. Call the destructor method of all child items in the object instance
2. Raise a `NotImplemented` error

But, I am not sure what overrides I need to define so that whenever pickle tries to serialize this object instance, I can perform those two tasks.

I.E., in pseudo code, is there some analog for:

```
def __pickle__(self):
  ...

# i.e.
def __<the function pickle looks for when it pickles>__(self):
  del x 
  del y
  del z
  ...
  raise NotImplemented("You Fool! Ahhh!!!")
```

Comment: Pickling seems to use the `__getstate__()` method as per: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2345944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `__getstate__` method.  This will be called when your object is pickled and you can do what you need to here.

```
def __getstate__(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("You Fool! Ahhh!!!")
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects