# Cannot pickle a yaml instance (ruamel)

Tags: python, yaml, pickle, ruamel.yaml

I'm trying to pickle a very large object and having some trouble with the following error (python 3.8.5):
`TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object`

I managed to narrow it down to a simple example:

test.yaml (irrelevant):

```
Hello there: General Kenobi
Universe: 42
```

The problem is seen here:

```
import pickle
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.yaml = YAML()
        with open("test.yaml", 'r') as yamlFile:
            self.my_yaml = self.yaml.load(yamlFile)

c = C()

with open("test.pkl", 'wb') as output:
    pickle.dump(c, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

From what I guess, the self.yaml holds a reference to the file stream.
Thing is I already loaded this file into my object and don't need it to be stored.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

I could delete the yaml instance before pickling and re-instantiate one after but I'd rather have it contained.

*EDIT:*

The above snippet is just a means to easily reproduce the error.
I actually use an object to store YAML and derived dictionnary methods. Other objects call this one instance to handle/dump their dictionnaries. The yaml instance is saved in an attribute because I've added representers other methods can use.
If the instance is only local, I'd need to redefine all the customization within each method

Comment: Just get rid of the `self.yaml` attribute - you use that value in the same method where it is generated, so there's no need for storing it anywhere that will persist.

Comment: If you *really* need the `yaml` field, you can [exclude it from pickling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2345944/347964).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, as said in my OP this is a simple example to replicate the error the actual usage is a bit more complex. I've precised this in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [flyx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347964/flyx) suggested, I managed to pickle the object [by excluding the yaml instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345944/exclude-objects-field-from-pickling-in-python) using `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you assign the `YAML()` instance to an attribute of the `C` instance, you can just use a normal variable, local to `__init__` and the pickling will not try to dump that:

```
import pathlib

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        yaml = YAML()
        yaml_file = pathlib.Path('test.yaml')
        self.my_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as said in my OP this is a simple example to reproduce the error the actual usage is a bit more complex. I've precised this in the OP.